# get $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] with iframe

Tags: php, javascript, colorbox

I'm working with Colorbox and if I specify to use an iframe with it then the $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] variable is no longer available to me. I need that in order to detect if ajax has loaded so then I can include a header/footer or not.

Anyway to get this variable or is there another variable that I can get when I use iframe?

Answer (score 1):

Setting/changing the `<iframe>`'s `src` attribute using JavaScript is definitely not using `XMLHttpRequest` to load the target page as you seem to think.

Rather pass an extra request parameter or pathinfo. E.g.

```
iframe.src = 'newpage.php?loadedByJS=true';
```

Which you in turn can check by `$_GET['loadedByJS']`.

Comment: Have you ever used colorbox? Below is the link that pops open the colorbox..you can see the colorbox_youtube class in the javascript code I posted earlier. I cannot just append a url variable to the below because there is no guarantee ajax has loaded 100%. I get what you are saying but I don't see how to do it Colorbox.
<a class="colorbox_youtube" href='file.php?id=<?php echo $_GET['id'];?>'>Copy to production</a>

Answer (score 0):

The variable name might be different you could try `print_r($_SERVER);`  to see the header is different.  Although a better approach would be to set a `$_GET` variable like `?ajax=true`

Comment: ya I did a var_dump($_SERVER) and couldn't find anything.

Comment: @keith  That server variable is only set by an XHR request,  if you are loading an iframe then its not going to be set.